# RavenDB - Adding Index breaks unrelated queries

Tags: indexing, ravendb

When I add the index below to my raven database a simple query like

```
return Session.Query<R>().FirstOrDefault(x => x.RId == Id);
```

Always returns null. Only after forcing Raven to remove my custom index does desired functionality return. Why is this?

The Index with side effects:

```
public class RByLatestCommentIndex : AbstractIndexCreationTask<R>
{
    public RByLatestCommentIndex()
    {
        SetMap();
    }

    void SetMap()
    {
        Map = r => r.Select(x => new
        {
            Id = x.Id,
            TimeStamp = x.Comments.Count() > 0 ? x.Comments.Max(u => u.Created)
                : x.Created
        }).OrderByDescending(y => y.TimeStamp).Select(r => new { Id = r.Id });
    }
}

public class RIdTransformer : AbstractTransformerCreationTask<R>
{
    public RIdTransformer()
    {
        TransformResults = ids => ids.Select(x => LoadDocument<R>(x.Id));
    }
}
```

EDIT:

In response to [Ayende Rahien's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6366/ayende-rahien) comment:

There's a query in the DB which would otherwise be used (Auto/R/ByRID) but the index used looks like this, puzzling enough:

```
from doc in docs.Rs select new { Images_Count__ = doc.Images["Count()"], RId = doc.RId }
```

What explains this behaviour? And, will I have to add a static index to be able to query R by RId ?

Comment: Check the query statistics, what index is it using for processing your query?

Comment: You shouldn't do `FirstOrDefault()` if you're trying to load `R` by ID, it's better to do `Load<R>(Id)` because it will not rely on a potentially-stale index query.